# Python GAE webapp2 output formatting

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm working now on my `retrieve` of values from `NDB`, which is a mess but it seems to be working:

```
class retrieve(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            id=(self.request.get('id'))
            newvalues=Book.get_by_id(id)
            newvalues=Book.to_dict(newvalues)
            newvalues=str(newvalues)
            self.response.write(newvalues)
```

This gets me :

```
{'content': u"(u'011', u'11', u'11', u'11', u'11')"}
```

I suppose I can convert that dict to a string and replace all the unwanted characters, as:

`newvalues = newvalues.replace ("{'content':","")`

Is there a simple / more efficient way?

The desired output:

```
01111111111
```

Ie. only values with no spaces or anything in between.

**EDIT 1**

@Daniel,

After implementing `values= ''.join(newvalues.content)`

I now have the `content` values:

`(u'011', u'11', u'11', u'11', u'11')`

Now do I need to `join` again to combine all that? Also, I thought that the `u` unicode notation goes away automagically...

**EDIT 2**
I do not know why this is happening.

I get the 'id' via `get_by_id` (removed the `to_dict` part), tried also:

```
 values= ''.join(newvalues.content)
 values=''.join(map(str, values))
 self.response.write (values)
```

Still only getting:

```
(u'011', u'11', u'11', u'11', u'11')
```

**EDIT `Book` model** :

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
        content = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Comment: how does your `Book` model look like?

Comment: @DanCornilescu, edited my question to reflect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.sub`

```
>>> d = {'content': u"(u'011', u'11', u'11', u'11', u'11')"}
>>> re.sub(r'u[\'"]|[\'",()\s]', '', d['content'])
u'01111111111'
>>> re.sub(r'u[\'"]|\W', '', d['content'])
u'01111111111'
```

Comment: thanks a lot.

I've thought about regex replacing but thought it wasn't very "pythonic"... and obviously had no idea how to implement, syntax-wise.. That actually works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be any reason to use `to_dict` here. Just access the `content` field directly:

```
values = ''.join(newvalues.content)
```

**Edit** The problem appears to be in how you are writing the content in the first place. For some reason you are storing the string representation of a tuple of strings, rather than either using a repeated field to store each string separately, or using JSON to store a proper serialization of the string in the first place.